# How to initialize a GitHub repo directly from Atom editor?

Tags: git, github, atom-editor

I am using Atom text editor and I want to connect it to GitHub. When I try to init and publish a repo to GitHub from Atom, it throws an error -

```
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Didn't find anything good on the web. Tried to reinstall the github package using apm and the command line, but got an error: `Failed to delete github: No package.json found at C:\Users\User\.atom\packages\github\package.json`

System - Windows 10, Atom - latest version.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to command line, just to check what origin is:

```
cd /path/to/local/repository
git remote -v
```

> when I try to init

Initialize alone would not set the origin: you need to add it manually:

```
cd /path/to/local/repository
git remote add origin https://url/remote/repository
```

Comment: It isn't about cloning, it is about creating and pushing a repo.

Comment: @Pythonista OK. I have modified the answer to address the pushing part, which depends on "origin" being defined.

Answer (score 1):

Got it. You should publish a repo using GitHub Desktop app, it works well and then Atom will work.

Comment: That will work too indeed: The GitHub Desktop app will set origin.